# Can you create "conjoined rectangles" using CSS and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to use CSS and jQuery to create a "rectangle row", with the following features?

```
vertical       vertical      vertical
border0        border1       border2
+----------------+------------+        / \
|                |            |         |
| rectangle0     | rectangle1 |         |  fixed height
|                |            |         |
+----------------+------------+        \ /

     resizable     resizable
 <--------------> <---------->
```

- The entire rectangle row is draggable (movable).
- Dragging vertical border i resizes the rectangle before it, if any, and the rectangle after it, if any.
- The rectangles can have different
  colors.

Below is some pseudocode.

CSS:

```
.rectangle-row {
  .rectangle0
  .rectangle1
}

.rectangle0 {
  width: 60px;
  background: pink;
}

.rectangle1 {
   width: 30px;
   background: yellow;
}
```

Javascript (using JQuery):

```
$(".rectangle-row").draggable();

$(".rectangle-row").resizable({
  minHeight: 40;
  maxHeight: 40; 
});

$(".rectangle0").resizable();
$(".rectangle1").resizable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try out my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDd5v/1/). I tried doing it with floating `divs` the problem is I don't see a way to cancel the resize event when all the rectangles width sum overflows the container. Might require a custom resize plugin.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="first rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="last rectangle"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Array.prototype.sum = function() {
  return (! this.length) ? 0 : this.slice(1).sum() +
      ((typeof this[0] == 'number') ? this[0] : 0);
};
var maxW = $('div.row').width();

$('div.rectangle').resizable({
    minHeight: 45, 
    maxHeight: 45,
    containment: 'parent',
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        var allW = $('div.rectangle').map(function(){ return $(this).width();}).get().sum();
        if(allW >= maxW){ // overflow, no way to stop
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is some *very* rough code. I didn't test it, nor do I plan to (your job is to make it work). If you had HTML like this (plus CSS for appropriate height and width, and float or position them inline):

```
<div class="area">
    <div class="vertical_border">(Remove me: Just a 1 pix wide border)</div>
    <div class="rectangle">Hello I'm a rect</div>
    <div class="vertical_border"></div>
    <div class="rectangle">Hello I'm a rect</div>
    <div class="vertical_border"></div>
    <div class="rectangle">Hello I'm a rect</div>
    <div class="vertical_border"></div>
</div>
```

And js like this:

```
var startX;
var leftRect = null;
var rightRect = null;
var isMoving = false;

$('.vertical_border').mousedown(function(e) {
    // Get the initial position of the mouse when you first click
    isMoving = true;
    startX = event.pageX;
    leftRect = $(this).prev('.rectangle');
    rightRect = $(this).next('.rectangle');
});

$('.area').mousemove(function(e) {
    // Updated the rectangles as the mouse is held and moving
    if(isMoving) {
        deltaX = e.pageX - startX
        // If you move the cursor left, deltaX is negative, so leftRect gets smaller
        leftRect.css('width', parseInt(leftRect.css('width')) + deltaX);
        // and rightRect gets bigger
        rightRect.css('width', parseInt(rightRect.css('width')) - deltaX);
    }
});

$('.area').mouseup(function(e) {
    // Disallow the rects from moving anymore when the user lets go
    isMoving = false;
});
```

The drag and drop can be handled by other jQuery plugins, I believe.

Comment: +1. Thank you for the pseudocode and calling for me to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yeah. I haven't the time to actually whip up a prototype, but I envision doing it with as simple markup as:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="rectangle1"></div>
    <div id="rectangle2"></div>
</div>
```

where the two child DIVs are floated.

You can set `#rectangle1` to be resizable (via jQueryUI), and constrain the resize to `#container` if you'd like.

What will happen is, the vertical border you want to drag around is essentially just the right border of `#rectangle1`. You can write a bit of script to resize `#rectangle2` as well by hooking up to the resize event of the resizable.

(Check the [docu page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#constrain-area) for both constrain and the resize event)

**UPDATE**

Here's a working prototype: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvcmQ/4/)

Using the markup above, you can:

1. Drag the container rectangle around.
2. Resize the any rectangle except the last
3. and the next rectangle resizes along with it to fit the container
4. while constraining the resize inside the container, and to not disturb the other rectangles.

All with minimal code and markup.